# UnsupportedOperationException while adding a string to a list through ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-arrayadapter

What I am trying to do here is add the word currently in the EditText at the press of "Enter/Done" on the softkey. However, each time I press the "Enter/Done" on the soft key, the app crashes.

I've tried to do some debugging and it appears that the issue seems to be the ***adapter.add(v.getText().toString());*** line. I am not sure why/how !!

```
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v,int actionId, KeyEvent event)    {
  Log.d("InThere","in onEditorAction1");
  if((event==NULL) || (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP))
  {
     if(event==NULL)
     Log.d("InThere","inside if+EVENT");
     if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
    Log.d("InThere","inside if+ACTION_UP");
     Log.d("InThere","before adapter ");
         adapter.add(v.getText().toString());      <<<cause of error ?
     Log.d("InThere","after adapter ");
     v.setText("");

     InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)
     getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
  }

  Log.d("InThere","in onEditorAction2");
  return true;
```

}

I created a filter with the tag "InThere" and here's what it looks like in the LogCat:

```
InThere         in onEditorAction1
InThere         in onEditorAction2
InThere         in onEditorAction1
InThere         inside if+ACTION_UP
InThere         before adapter
```

Also, could you help me understand why the string is being obtained through an instance of TextView in the onEditorAction function when actually it is actually being obtained from EditText  ?

[UPDATE]

Here's the declaration part of the code....

```
private final static String[] items={"this","is","a","really","silly","list"};
 private static final KeyEvent NULL = null;
   private ArrayList<String> words=null;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        words = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String s: items)
        {
            words.add(s); 
        }
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: What is the class of adapter?

Comment: Yeah what is the adapter class? Also check your LogCat for the stacktrace, that is the import log to read! Will tell you the exact error

Comment: `EditText` is a subclass of `TextView` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Comment: @Blundell or @Wand Maker :  Oh! So sorry about that. It's declared as  `private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;`  **within the same class** i.e MainActivity.java

Comment: show us where you say `new ArrayAdapter`

Comment: @Blundell i've added an [UPDATE] to my query above..sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: lol you keep leaving things out!!! Where is `items` defined

Comment: @Blundell me bad :\ , please check it now....

Comment: Use an `ArrayList` containing the *items* values and pass that to the `ArrayAapter`. Otherwise the adapter will create a non mutable list from the array you pass in for which the `add`/`remove` methods don't work and throw the error you see.

Comment: @user2499998 Don't forget to accept the right answer by clicking the check-mark in the side of answer.

Comment: @Luksprog : thanks alot... helped me zero in on the issue...  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah as suspected, your `ArrayAdapter` is backed by an `array`.

`Array` does not support the add operation.

Change it to be back by an ArrayList. ie:

```
private final static List<String> items = new ArrayList();
static {
  items.add("this");
  items.add("is");
  items.add("a");
  items.add("really");
  items.add("silly");
  items.add("list");
}
```

---

As WandMaker hinted, you seem to have done some work to create an ArrayList already, another solution could be:

```
 adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);
```

---

The optimum solution (with your code) being:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.add("this");
        words.add("is");
        words.add("a");
        words.add("really");
        words.add("silly");
        words.add("list");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Where is it backed by an array?  He has words = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: @WandMaker no need to -1 just because *you* don't get it. It is backed  by an array here in his question: `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);`

Comment: But your solution is unnecessarily asking to create a static variable. You can fix the answer by telling him to pass the "words" as parameter instead of "items"  I have removed -1, your solution is not right though.

Comment: @WandMaker it is static in his question!

Comment: @Blundell Thank you, it's worked now. It dawned on me after I read your **"another solution"** part... So from what I understand now, an `array` _cannot_ be passed on to an `ArrayAdapter` because it's size cannot be increased at `runtime`, correct?

Comment: @WandMaker Thank you, helped me understand the overall issue.  :)